# How can I paste the data from different workbooks that come from same sheets into one final workbook, but in different ranges/columns?

Tags: excel, vba

So I've been trying to make a macro so that I could extract data from a certain folder with a lot of information, but exact same sheets and ranges, to a single file, but I've encountered a problem while looping through files. There's a certain pattern I need the data to be pasted in, Currently, my loop copies the data I need from all the workbooks, but pastes it to the same location and I was wondering how Could I make the range change with every file. F.e. A1:J168 is pasted into A4:J171 and P10 into J4, from the next workbook I'd like it to be pasted into L4:U171 and U4 accordingly, and so on, the distance between these ranges is basically 1 column and I want it to loop as long as there are files in the folder.

```
Option Explicit

Const FOLDER_PATH = "C:\Users\mapetr\Desktop\Duomenys\"  'NEPAMIRSTI PASIKEISTI

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   Dim sFile As String
   Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
   Dim wbSource As Workbook
   Dim wsSource1 As Worksheet
   Dim wsSource2 As Worksheet

   If Not FileFolderExists(FOLDER_PATH) Then
      MsgBox "Specified folder does not exist, exiting!"
      Exit Sub
   End If

   On Error GoTo errHandler
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   Set wsTarget = Sheets("Routings (fin)")

   sFile = Dir(FOLDER_PATH & "*.xls*")
   Do Until sFile = ""
  
      Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(FOLDER_PATH & sFile)
      Set wsSource1 = wbSource.Worksheets("Summary for finance")
      Set wsSource2 = wbSource.Worksheets("PBA box build cost calculation")
  
      'DUOMENU IMPORTAS
      With wsTarget
         .Range("A4:J171").Value = wsSource1.Range("A1:J168").Value
         .Range("J4").Value = wsSource2.Range("P10").Value
         
      End With
  
      wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
      sFile = Dir()
   Loop

errHandler:
   On Error Resume Next
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   Set wsSource1 = Nothing
   Set wsSource2 = Nothing
   Set wbSource = Nothing
   Set wsTarget = Nothing
End Sub


Private Function FileFolderExists(strPath As String) As Boolean
    If Not Dir(strPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then FileFolderExists = True
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An offset with a counter should do it:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim sFile As String
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wsSource1 As Worksheet
    Dim wsSource2 As Worksheet
    
    If Not FileFolderExists(FOLDER_PATH) Then
       MsgBox "Specified folder does not exist, exiting!"
       Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error GoTo errHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wsTarget = Sheets("Routings (fin)")
    Dim i As Long, colAmt As Long 'i is the counter here
    colAmt = 11 'A:J = 10 + 1 extra
    sFile = Dir(FOLDER_PATH & "*.xls*")
    Do Until sFile = ""
    
        Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(FOLDER_PATH & sFile)
        Set wsSource1 = wbSource.Worksheets("Summary for finance")
        Set wsSource2 = wbSource.Worksheets("PBA box build cost calculation")
        
        'DUOMENU IMPORTAS
        With wsTarget
           .Range("A4:J171").Offset(, i * colAmt).Value = wsSource1.Range("A1:J168").Value
           .Range("J4").Offset(, i * colAmt).Value = wsSource2.Range("P10").Value
           
        End With
        
        wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
        sFile = Dir()
        i = i + 1
     Loop
FinishSub:            
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume FinishSub
End Sub
```

Let me know if something is unclear or doesn't work :)

Comment: Note that in case of a runtime error the routine will silently quit without giving any hint. Also, it is not necessary to assign `Nothing` to all the variables at the end.

Comment: I just addressed the issue at hand but you're right, they're not necessary but how OP wants to do error handling is to him.

Comment: Made an edit for some basic error handling @FunThomas , let me know if I need to adjust it, I'm too much of a beginner with error handling for now so all the help is welcome.

Comment: A useful error handling is always tricky. When you use the macros only for yourself or some colleagues that are nearby, I usually don't use error handling at all - let the runtime show the error and press "Debug", this helps to identify the error because you see the line where the problem occurred and can check with the debugger the variables and the call stack. Anyhow, your version will do the trick: showing at least that something failed.

Comment: I'm learning my way from making macros for a small company (and here ofc) so unless it isn't for my team of 4, I do the same; just letting VBA tell me where it occurs and fixing it on the go where needed. Thanks for the input.